# Valgrind: shared libraries for the executable program could not be loaded

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, valgrind

I have some weird memory related errors in my program.

It uses intel mkl and therefore depends upon some mkl specific shared libraries.

When I run my program, it segfaults after it has done most of the work. The segfaults occurs in the function call fclose() to a file pointer that is not null.

When I run my program through gdb, the stacktrace is not very useful.

I therefore wanted to run valgrind to find possible errors in my code.

But, I cannot run the executable from valgrind. It prints the following error message.

```
==52778== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==52778== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==52778== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==52778== Command: ./main.exe
==52778==
./main.exe: error while loading shared libraries: libmkl_intel_lp64.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The shared library libmkl_intel_lp64.so is present in the same directory (as well as all other shared libraries that my executable depends upon).

How do I resolve this problem, so that I can valgrind my code?

Thanks.

Edit: I also set (and checked) the environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH to the current directory, but it did not help.

Edit: Running on Linux 64 bit, using intel compilers 2017

Comment: What platform are you running on? `./main.exe` indicates you are running on windows from within powershell (unless you just added `-o main.exe` to your `gcc` compile string on Linux for some strange reason). If you are on windows, are you using MinGW, MinGW-TDM, what? When setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` did you use windows or POSIX path notation (e.g. `c:/path/to/your/lib`)?

Comment: Running on Linux. Using intel compilers.

Comment: That helps -- the `.exe` really caught me off guard. Recompile `main.exe` adding `-Wl,-rpath=/path/to/dir`   that has `libmkl_intel_lp64.so` and try again.

Comment: It worked. :) The rpath option did it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The shared library libmkl_intel_lp64.so is present in the same
>   directory (as well as all other shared libraries that my executable
>   depends upon).
>
> How do I resolve this problem, so that I can valgrind my code?

`valgrind` provides much of it's own environment and wrappers for various functions in order to do its job. Since you have set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and are still experiencing problems finding your library, your other option is to provide the library search path within the executable itself using the linker option `-rpath=/path/to/dir` that contains the library. The addition to the compile string would be:

```
-Wl,-rpath=/path/to/dir   /* that has libmkl_intel_lp64.so in it */
```

Then finding the library doesn't depend on the external environment or the hope that `valgind` will extend its library search to the current working directory.

(glad it worked)

Comment: Its sad its 2017 and Linux paths are still so f**k'd up. Their latest gadget to attempt to fix paths adds some DT bits. Now you have to use `-Wl,--enable-new-dtags`.